# Infopath 2010 saved as 2007 with code behind 2007 generate error

Tags: c#, infopath

I created infopath form with code behind. My mistake was that i did it in 2010 with form file type of form 2007.  conversion didnt go well... i removed all code from form, and when i tried to add from beginig i cant even open this form with error " Infopath canno open this form" any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start fresh and manually copy the code in. Open the code file in notepad, paste it into your new InfoPath form.